# can I run two nodes on LAN?

Tags: bitcoind

I am attempting to get two nodes to talk to each other on the testnet, both nodes are on the same LAN.  After starting both nodes with the other node's ip address I get the following error when I check the status:

error: couldn't connect to server

In the debug.log file I have the following output:

```
msghand thread start
dumpaddr thread start
trying connection 192.168.1.121:8272 lastseen=359579.6hrs
init message: Done loading
connected 192.168.1.121:8272
send version message: version 70001, blocks=0, us=0.0.0.0:0, them=0.0.0.0:0, peer=192.168.1.121:8272
Added time data, samples 2, offset -18 (+0 minutes)
receive version message: version 70001, blocks=0, us=0.0.0.0:0, them=124.3.14.162:8272, peer=192.168.1.121:8272
getblocks -1 to 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 limit 500
trying connection 124.3.14.162:8272 lastseen=2.5hrs
connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
trying connection 124.3.14.162:8272 lastseen=2.5hrs
connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
```

Public IP: 124.3.14.162

If two nodes are on the same LAN and they both get the same public IP, will that cause this error?

Comment: Maybe you want to give `bitcoin-testnet-box` a go: https://github.com/freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box

Comment: They need to connect to each other using their private IPs.